# check if a value exist in array from database query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to build a website that will display the text in multiple languages.
I have a table 'text' with all the languages. If the text does not exist in the chosen language it has to display the default language.

query SELECT * FROM `text` WHERE TextId = 10
results in

```
Id  TextId  LanguageId  Text
10  10      1           first name
13  10      2           名前
```

If I r_print this result I get something like this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 10 [Id] => 10 [1] => 10 [TextId] => 10 [2] => 1 [LanguageId] => 1 [3] => first name [Text] => first name ) 
        [1] => Array ( [0] => 13 [Id] => 13 [1] => 10 [TextId] => 10 [2] => 2 [LanguageId] => 2 [3] => 名前 [Text] => 名前 ) )
```

How can I check that LanguageId 2 exist in this array ?
the problem is that it is possible that TextId 2 and Id 2 can also exist in this array.

Is this possible to do with `in_array()`?

Comment: in_array() is possible..                                              i have used to same problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that can check if LanguageId equals a special value .

```
function isLanguageIdExists($yourArray , $LanguageId){
    $exists=false;
    foreach($yourArray as $array){
     if(isset($array['LanguageId'])&& $array['LanguageId'] == $LanguageId){
        $exists=true;break;
      }

    }
    return $exists;
}

$exist = isLanguageIdExists($yourArray , 2);//return true or false
```

Comment: this function can also be modified to check other keys like `textId`, `Id` , just introduce a 3rd paramter in the function for array key , the value you want to check is already being passed

Answer (score 0):

You can check by isset the key and match the value in php.

```
$dataArray =  array(
    0 => array(0 => 10 ,'Id' => 10, 1 => 10, 'TextId' => 10, 2 => 1, 'LanguageId' => 1),1 => array(0 => 10 ,'Id' => 10, 1 => 10, 'TextId' => 10, 2 => 1, 'LanguageId' => 1)

);

foreach($dataArray as $value) {
    if(isset($value['LanguageId']) && $value['LanguageId'] == 2) {
        echo 'language ID 2 is available';
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](http://ideone.com/M3s0pw)</kbd>

Comment: I feel like a complete idiot to not have thought about isset().
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

After giving this some more thought I came up with a maybe not so elegant solution.
Instead of getting an array back I modified the SQL Query to give one row back with the default language (English) and a user selected language (Japanese).
It uses two left joins. This shows that I received (some) training in SQL but am really not at ease with multidimensional arrays.

Query
def_text = text in default language
usr_text = text in user chosen language

```
    $table01 = "text";
    $query="SELECT $table01.TextId, 
            text_def.Text as def_text,
            text_usr.Text as usr_text
            FROM $table01 
            LEFT JOIN $table01 as text_def ON $table01.TextId = text_def.TextId AND text_def.LanguageId = $_SESSION[default_language]
            LEFT JOIN $table01 as text_usr ON $table01.TextId = text_usr.TextId AND text_usr.LanguageId = $_SESSION[language]
            WHERE $table01.TextId=$mess;";
```

after getting back the results it is easy to check with isset() or empty() to see if the text is available in the user selected language